# PHPExcel comentario en negro

Tags: php, excel

Llevamos un tiempo usando PHPexcel para rellenar unas tablas desde la Base de Datos, lleva funcionando meses pero últimamente al escribir un comentario y remodificar el Excel el cuadro de comentario aparece negro...

No ha habido cambio de código alguno lo que me lleva a pensar que puede ser alguna actualización de Office (usamos office 365), ¿a alguien más le ha pasado o tiene alguna idea de qué puede ser? 
Gracias!

[image: Como nos aparece ahora]

[image: Como debería salir]

Si selecciono el texto y le cambio el color aparece, por lo que pienso que puede ser que se esté cambiando el background del comentario.

Comment: ¿Hubo algún cambio en el código? ¿Alguna actualización de soft o cambio de entorno? ¿Aparece así en 1 cliente o en todos? Los comentarios toman el color de los tooltips del sistema. ¿Cómo están configurados?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo visto ha sido debido a una mal configuración en Windows, probablemente por alguna actualización.

La solución ha sido:

1. Click derecho sobre el escritorio
2. Personalizar
3. Color de ventana
4. Configuración avanzada de la apariencia
5. En el dropdown de Elemento busca "Información sobre herramientas" y a la derecha el Color 1 debe de estar en el color blanco-beige, si te sale negro cámbialo ya que es lo que está generando el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Lo único que se me ocurre es, que tengáis algún problema por un "contador de comentarios" y ese contador haya excedido el número máximo permitido por el tipo de variable.
En Excel
El máximo `Byte` es 255
El máximo `Integer` es 32767
El máximo `Long` es 2.147.483.647
.
.
.
No se si tendrá algo que ver, pero me recuerda a un problema que tuve en un foro que gestionaba, ya que dejaron de aparecer los comentarios y fue por eso, el contador estaba declarado como `int` y superamos los 2.147.483.647

Espero que te ayude, un saludo.